# Instead of catching exceptions, the try and catch blocks give result as infinity

Tags: java, c++, try-catch

In both my java an C++ programs, I have put a simple try/catch block to catch a divide by zero exception. Instead of addressing the problem, the program says the answer is infinity. Why is this happening?

Java (C++ almost exactly like this):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.ArithmeticException;
public class Expiriment {



    static double a;
    static double b;


    public static void main (String [] args){

        try {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter first Number");
            a = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter 2nd number");
            b = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Answer is:"+ a/b);  

        }
        catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            double f = 0;
            System.err.println (e+" "+"Cannot perform operation.");
            System.out.println("Answer is:" + f);
        }


        }

    }
```

Comment: Because `a/0` is infinity in floating-point arithemtic (assuming `a != 0`).  If you want to prevent divide-by-zero, just directly test the value of `b` before you do the division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not compare Java's try/catch with C++'s try/catch.  Division by zero in a C++ program is *not* a C++ exception.

Please see here:

[Catching exception: divide by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121623/catching-exception-divide-by-zero)

Answer (score 2):

IEEE754 floating point division is defined to return infinity for nonzero a and 0 b, or NaN if you divide 0/0. Hence, you get such a result in your print statement.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point):

> Division by zero (an operation on finite operands gives an exact infinite result, e.g., `1/0`or `log(0)`) (returns `±infinity` by default).