# Why cannot catch c++ exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, crash

IF I write code and throw exceptions in c++ , i can can catch these exceptions as well.Example;

```
int divide(int divison, int dividor)
{
    if (dividor == 0)
        throw DivideByZeroException();
    return divison / dividor;
}
void main()
{
    int a = 10,b=0;
    try
    {
        result = divide(a, b);
        cout << "result : " << result << endl;
    }
    catch (exception & e)
    {
        cout <<  e.what() << endl;
    }   
    cout << "Enter a key to exit" << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

However if I try to catch same exception program crashes directly.Example

```
void main()
{
    int a = 10,b=0;
    try
    {
        result = a / b;
        cout << "result : " << result << endl;
    }
    catch (exception & e)
    {
        cout << "Normal exception :" << e.what() << endl;
    }
    cout << "Enter a key to exit" << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

Why is this happening and is there a way that stops program crash when an error occured in c++ ?

Comment: DivideByZeroException is a class inherited from std::exception.

Comment: Integer division is not an exception in C++. See [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121623/catching-exception-divide-by-zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, a division by 0 won't generate an exception : the behavior is undefined (on many OS, the kernel will send a signal to the program, and if you don't catch it, the program terminates).

C++ Standard, section 5/4

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined.

You can (should) check for your inputs before doing a division : the language won't do it for you. (Some numeric library encapsulate primitive types, and overloads operators, and do throw exceptions)

Comment: Yes it seems using try-catch's in programs is not couraged.As far as I searched people offer to use returning 0 from functions instead of throwing exceptions.Can we say that if a c++ code has exception it will crash , try catch wont save us for most of the cases.