# Redirect c++ crash to stderr

Tags: c++

Considering a small program like this :

```
int main()
{
    freopen("./stdout.log", "w", stdout);
    freopen("./stderr.log", "w", stderr);

    int a = 1 / 0;
}
```

and considering my program is ran by a third party software where I can't change neither how the program is launched nor the environment.

How to properly catch the `Floating point exception (core dumped)` message issued by the division by zero and any other messages that would still be printed on the tty ?

I've tried to search SO for similar answer but I might be just typing the wrong keywords as it seems a common practice.

Comment: You need to catch the signals, which is platform dependent.

Comment: Have you get a look to std::terminate_handler ?

Comment: @Gojita Despite its name `Floating point exception` is a signal (`SIGFPE`), not an `std::exception`

Comment: That's operating system dependant.  You need to specify the operating system your _third party_ is running that program on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matthieu Brucher's comment is correct:

> You need to catch the signals, which is platform dependent.

From the text of the message, I infer that you may be running on a Linux platform. If so, you can [catch the `SIGFPE` signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121623/catching-exception-divide-by-zero).

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <signal.h>

// compile with -fnon-call-exceptions (for gcc)
signal(SIGFPE, [](int signum) { throw std::logic_error("FPE"); });
```

The linked answer has some C++ niceties such as using a `std::shared_ptr` for RAII management of the signal handler and mentions compiler flags needed for gcc to make that work.

The Linux Programming Interface book also has a [pure-C example](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/diff/signals/demo_SIGFPE.c.html).

---

In Windows, you can use [Structured Exception Handling (SEH)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/floating-point-exceptions) and the concept is similar (although the functions you need to call are not).

---

Note that in either case you're relying on platform-specific behavior not specified by C++ (division by zero is undefined behavior) so obviously this will not result in portable code.

Comment: Super bad idea. Throwing `std::exception` from from signal handler is a recipe for a mighty disaster

Comment: @SergeyA I agree and edited the answer. That part came from the linked answer, and I left it alone assuming they knew something I didn't.

Comment: @SergeyA Actually, I am reverting the edit, as it seems my original thought (that they knew something I didn't) was accurate: gcc with `-fnon-call-exceptions` [does allow this to work](https://scc.ustc.edu.cn/zlsc/sugon/intel/compiler_c/main_cls/copts/ccpp_options/option_fnon_call_exceptions.htm). The documentation specifically mentions SIGFPE as a use case.

Comment: Than you need to add this information to the answer, and be super-specific about compiler. Alternatively, since your answer doesn't add much to the other answer you linked, you can delete your answer and close this question as a duplicate. As it stands, your answer is a (bastardized to the point of being incorrect) copy.

Comment: @Sergey I do mention the necessary gcc flag in the answer, and I don't see how it is "wrong" in any way. I augmented the other answer with information about other platforms, in a way that won't fit in a comment. I will leave the answer as-is; if mods wish to delete it or close, that's fine. I appreciate your input but please be respectful.