# floating point exception not catchable?

Tags: c++, exception, floating-point

I have a problem with the floating point exception. When i divide by zero, i get this exception. I tried to catch it, but the solutions on the internet don't work for me.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

double h{0};
int a{0},b{0},c{0};

cin.exceptions(ios_base::failbit);

cout << "Enter Values: ";
try{ 
  cin >> a >> b >> c;  
  h = (3/1/a+1/b+1/c);      

if(a == 0 || b == 0 || c == 0){
 throw overflow_error("Division by zero is not allowed!");
}
  cout << h;
}
catch(overflow_error e){
     cerr << e.what();
 }
 catch(exception& e){
     cerr << "Only numbers!";
 }
 catch(...){
    cerr << "?";
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are many kind of exceptions, not all of them are C++ exceptions. And you can only catch a C++ exception that is thrown with the C++ statement `throw`.

Comment: and how excactly i can throw it?

Comment: The right-hand-side of the `h=` assignment just contains integers, so you are only performing integer-divisions by zero (not floating-point). Integer-Division by zero is undefined behavior (i.e., it could crash or give unexpected results or (less likely) format your hard-drive)

Comment: this is the scope, h have to be a float

Comment: You could check [the floating point environment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv). And depending on compiler and OS you could look into *structured exceptions*.

Comment: i think at the moment this is to high for my level. Can you simpley explain, how to chatch a exception that is not a c++ exception?

Comment: With `catch`? You can't. If you you don't feel comfortable manipulating or checking the FP-environment or with structured exceptions, then your only solution is input validation to make sure you never get e.g. division by zero.

Comment: why its not possiple? its the task, so there should be a soulution. The problem is, that i dont exactly understand what you mean. Can you show me a sample?

Comment: Time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve]. Most importantly, *what is "the task"?*

Comment: what has this to do with my question? I think the question is clear enough. If you don't  wanna help you are free to go. I

Comment: No, you cannot catch a floating point exception with `catch` (and why you think you can catch it with `catch(int&)` is a complete mystery). FPE is not a C++ exception. It is undefined behaviour to divide by 0. Your platform may offer platform-specific ways to handle this situation, so if you have an assignment to do that, you should ask your professor which platform(s) you need to target.

Comment: i have catched it successfully . so... why you think its not possible. Look at me edited code

Comment: You didn't catch a division by zero. You caught an exception you have thrown yourself, which is of course possible.

Comment: That what i wanted. Too stop the the floating point exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re getting a “floating point exception” (which is not a C++ exception), that's why its not catchable.

https://www.quora.com/Why-isn%E2%80%99t-this-catch-block-in-C++-catching-any-exception

I suggest [guarding](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/02/20/on-using-guards-in-cpp/) for input validation.

In your code, the exception happens before you start throwing stuff.

Comment: i know, but with catch(...) i can catch all variants of exceptions?

Comment: No, only cpp ones, and “floating point exception” is not one of them.

Comment: ah okay thanks, what i have to change to caught it?

Comment: Why don't you validate input and save yourself the cost of throwing exceptions ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121623/catching-exception-divide-by-zero
This should help you.

Comment: how i can validate the input?

Comment: Of course if they are 0, throw an exception and do NOT proceed. Have you done that ?

Comment: i already did that. It is the same as with my code that i post

Comment: the soulution has to be done with exception. What do you exactly mean if they are 0 throw an exception? What exception i have to throw?

Comment: You're checking AFTER trying to divide. Make the check BEFORE doing h = (3/1/a+1/b+1/c);