# try catch mechanism in c++

Tags: c++, try-catch

I honestly searched and tried to implement try - catch mechanism in C++, but I failed: I don't have enough experience yet. In Android there is a convenient way to catch general exceptions, whether it's a division by zero or an array out-of-bounds, like

```
int res;
int a=1;
int b=0;

try{res = a/b;}
catch(Exception e)
{
    int stop=1;
};
```

Works fine, program does not crash.

Could you please tell me how to make an universal exceptions interceptor in C++, if possible.

Comment: Can [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-catch-all-the-exceptions-in-cplusplus) help ?

Comment: `catch(...)` is about as "universal" as you'll get in terms of a catch-all, but it won't catch things like divide-by-zero, segfaults etc which are generally the responsibility of the programmer to avoid.

Comment: Division by zero or out-of-bounds array accesses (and many other things) do not throw C++ exceptions - they have undefined behaviour. It is the programmer's responsibilty to check before trying.

Comment: @Scryper That link doesn't explain anything. The grammar of several sentences isn't even correct and aside from that basically all sentences are not-quite-right in content.

Comment: This gets confusing, because the OS claims that some errors are exceptions, but that's a different word from "exception" in C++. In C++ you can only `catch` something that you `throw`. If it doesn't say `throw` it's not an exception.

Comment: did the provided answer help you? if so, please consider upvoting / accepting it. if not, feel free to comment on what aspect ia still unclear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ has a diverse range of error handling for different problems.

Division by zero and many other errors (null pointer access, integer overflow, array-out-of-bounds) do not cause an exception that you can catch.

You could use tools such as clang's [undefined behavior sanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) to detect some of them, but that requires some extra work on your part, and comes with a performance hit.

The best way in C++ to deal with prevention of a division by zero, is to check for it:

```
    int res;
    int a=1;
    int b=0;

    if (b == 0)
    {
        int stop=1;
    }
    else
    {
        res = a/b;
    }
```

See also [the answers to this other very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121623/catching-exception-divide-by-zero).