# Why am I experiencing unexpected behavior with Linux signal handling?

Tags: linux, windows, unix, signals, aix

I live in an environment with Win7/MSVC 2010sp1, two different Linux boxes (Red Hat) with g++ versions (4.4.7, 4.1.2), and AIX with xlc++ (08.00.0000.0025).

Not so long ago it was requested that we move some code from AIX over to Linux.  It didn't take too long to see that Linux was a bit different.  Normally when a signal is thrown, we handle it and throw a C++ exception.  That was not working as expected.

[Long story short, throwing c++ exceptions from a signal handler isn't going to work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717991/throwing-an-exception-from-within-a-signal-handler)

Sometime later, I put together a fix that uses setjmp/longjmp to move the exception out of the handler.  Aftersome testing and the dang thing works on all platforms.  After an obligatory round of cubical happy dance I moved on to setting up some unit tests.  Oops.

Some of my tests were failing on Linux.  What I observed was that the raise function only worked once.  With two tests using SIGILL, the first one passed, and the second one failed.  I broke out an axe, and started chopping away at the code to remove as much cruft as possible.  That yielded this smaller example.

```
#include <csetjmp>
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>

jmp_buf  mJmpBuf;
jmp_buf *mpJmpBuf = &mJmpBuf;
int status = 0;
int testCount = 3;

void handler(int signalNumber)
{
    signal(signalNumber, handler);
    longjmp(*mpJmpBuf, signalNumber);
}

int main(void)
{
    if (signal(SIGILL, handler) != SIG_ERR)
    {
        for (int test = 1; test <= testCount; test++)
        {
            try
            {
                std::cerr << "Test " << test << "\n";
                if ((status = setjmp(*mpJmpBuf)) == 0)
                {
                    std::cerr << "    About to raise SIGILL" << "\n";
                    int returnStatus = raise(SIGILL);
                    std::cerr << "    Raise returned value " << returnStatus
                              << "\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cerr << "    Caught signal. Converting signal "
                              << status << " to exception" << "\n";
                    std::exception e;
                    throw e;
                }
                std::cerr << "    SIGILL should have been thrown **********\n";
            }
            catch (std::exception &)
            { std::cerr << "    Caught exception as expected\n"; }
        }
    }
    else
    { std::cerr << "The signal handler wasn't registered\n"; }

    return 0;
}
```

For the Windows and the AIX boxes I get the expected output.

```
Test 1
    About to raise SIGILL
    Caught signal. Converting signal 4 to exception
    Caught exception as expected Test 2
    About to raise SIGILL
    Caught signal. Converting signal 4 to exception
    Caught exception as expected Test 3
    About to raise SIGILL
    Caught signal. Converting signal 4 to exception
    Caught exception as expected
```

For both Linux boxes it looks like this.

```
Test 1
    About to raise SIGILL
    Caught signal. Converting signal 4 to exception
    Caught exception as expected
Test 2
    About to raise SIGILL
    Raise returned value 0
    SIGILL should have been thrown **********
Test 3
    About to raise SIGILL
    Raise returned value 0
    SIGILL should have been thrown **********
```

So, my real question is "**What is going on here?**"

My retorical questions are:

- Is anyone else observing this behavior?
- What should I do to try to troubleshoot this issue?
- What other things should I be aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `sigsetjmp`/`siglongjmp` to ensure the correct behavior when mixing signals and jumps. If you change your code it will correctly work under Linux.

You also used the old signal API which not recommended. I encourage you to use the much more reliable `sigaction` interface. The first benefits will be that you have no more need to reset the signal catch in the handler...