# Throwing an Exception from a Signal Handler for Segmentation Fault C++ Linux Debian

Tags: c++11, exception, segmentation-fault, signals

I have a requirement to gracefully discard messages if they throw a segmentation fault and continue to listen to the next message in queue. For implementing the same, I have installed a signal handler function for segmentation fault, which throws a runtime exception, and the catch block handles the code for discarding the message.

I have used the compiler flag **-fnon-call-exceptions** when compiling. I observed that the exception gets caught for some messages but fails sometimes going past the catch block and aborts with the below error.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  Segmentation Fault
Aborted (core dumped)

I have also tried adding the jump functions, sigsetjmp and siglongjmp, but it disturbs the flow of code execution and there is an issue when listening to the next message in queue.

I am expecting the code to be able to catch the runtime exception for all messages.

The following is my sample code, which is compiled with the flag -fnon-call-exceptions. It is giving mixed results. Expecting it to work at all times.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include <setjmp.h>
 

using namespace std;
void catch_signal(int signalNumber)
{
    throw(10);
}

void testFunc(char* x)
{
    *x = 100;
}
void service_sigset() {
  signal(SIGSEGV, catch_signal);
    try
    {
        testFunc(0);
    }
    catch (int &z)
    {
        cerr << "Caught exception: " << z << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    try
    { 
        service_sigset();
    }
    catch(int &z)
    {
        std::cout << "runtime error caught!!!" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please guide me here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Throwing an exception from within a signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717991/throwing-an-exception-from-within-a-signal-handler)

Comment: no, I tried using the jmp functions, but unfortunately, facing an issue where I am unable to get notified when the next message is coming on queue.